# fullpage.js Section scroll disable in mobile still section getting scroll automatically

Tags: jquery, html, fullpage.js

Hi guys I am facing a strange issue in Fullpage.js

while I stopped autoscroll in mobile devices, if a section is half scrolled in mobile device it is automatically scrolling to the section top. **[appsolution](http://dev.innvonix.in/appsolution)** on this Link I am facing the issue.

Comment: Working as expected now ?

Comment: Yes @Alvaro it is working better as expected Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Hi @alvaro I am facing another issue on mobile too that once I move to a section touch stop working and not getting back to any other section.in the same url **[appsolution](http://dev.innvonix.com/appsolution)**